# How to subtract two dates and get the difference in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, date

I'm trying to subtract two HTML date types and extract the difference, in days.

`ci` and `co` stand for check in and check out

```js
document.getElementById('co').valueAsDate = new Date(86400000 + +new Date())
document.getElementById('ci').valueAsDate = new Date();

var date1 = document.getElementById('ci').value;
var date2 = document.getElementById('co').value;

const diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); // find diffdate

document.getElementById('diffday').value = diffDays;
```

```html
<input id="ci" type="date" class="datepicker" min="1">
<input id="co" type="date" class="datepicker">
<input id="diffday" type="number" min="0">
<label for="day">diffday</label>
```

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @TheAlpha93 the poster is subtracting two input (string) values instead of dates.

Comment: Rather than *Math.ceil* you should use *Math.round*, as if the date range crosses a daylight saving boundary, it may result in an extra day. Similarly, `new Date(86400000 + +new Date())` will occasionally not add a whole day.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are retrieving the input field value as a date and not a string.

You already used [`valueAsDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties) to set the value, so use it again for retrieval.

```js
const DAY_IN_MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

const main = () => {
  let now = new Date();
  document.getElementById('co').valueAsDate = new Date(DAY_IN_MILLIS + +now)
  document.getElementById('ci').valueAsDate = now;

  // Add change event listeners
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker')).forEach(dp => {
    dp.addEventListener('change', onDateChange);
  });
  
  triggerEvent(document.getElementById('co'), 'change'); // Trigger change
};

const onDateChange = (e) => {
  const date1 = document.getElementById('ci').valueAsDate; // <-- Here
  const date2 = document.getElementById('co').valueAsDate; // <-- Here
  const diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
  const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / DAY_IN_MILLIS); // find diffdate
  document.getElementById('diffday').value = diffDays;
};

const triggerEvent = (el, eventName) => {
  var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  event.initEvent(eventName, true, false);
  el.dispatchEvent(event);
};

main();
```

```html
<input id="ci" type="date" class="datepicker" min="1">
<input id="co" type="date" class="datepicker">
<input id="diffday" type="number" min="0">
<label for="day">diffday</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

`date1` and `date2` return strings representing the dates. Which, if you want to calculate days difference you need to convert to unix timestamps first.

Like so:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input id="ci" type="date" class="datepicker" min="1" >
    <input id="co" type="date" class="datepicker">
    <input id="diffday" type="number" min="0">
    <label for="day">diffday</label>

    <script>
      document.getElementById('co').valueAsDate = new Date(86400000 + new Date().getTime())
      document.getElementById('ci').valueAsDate = new Date();
      var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('ci').value);
      var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById('co').value);
      const diffTime = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
      const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
      //find diffdate
      document.getElementById('diffday').value=diffDays;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What was happening was that `var diffTime = "2020-06-16" - "2020-06-15"` which returns `NaN`

Working example [in this codepen](https://codepen.io/jasperdg/pen/pogEvVM?editors=1111)

Comment: but when i manually change date from html input, why different date not change ?

Comment: You'd need to have `onChange` events on all of the `input` fields. Right now it only set's the variables once.